# maven-jetty-plugin ignores my classes and properties

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, overlays

given this configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
            <configuration>
                <jettyConfig>${basedir}/src/main/config/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
                <jettyEnvXml>${project.build.directory}/jetty/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</classesDirectory>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>8.3-603.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.2</version>
                </dependency>                   
            </dependencies>             
        </plugin>
```

I have some new values in src/main/java/com.mypackage/myproperties.properties
which is a perfect copy of src/main/java/com.mypackage/myproperties.properties coming from a WAR declared as a dependency in the pom.xml

When I start mvn jetty:run , the overlay takes place, and my file is in target/classes instead of the original one, with the new values as expected.

BTW jetty keeps serving the original file and I can't really figure out why or from where.

Thanks for any hints, I've been spending almost 8 hours searching and experimenting on this...

Bau,
Wiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that Jetty wants a full package with all its classes (and .properties) otherwise it just won't allow the single new file to override the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Maven caches files for the jetty plugin in a [local repository](http://code.google.com/p/ftse/wiki/EclipseMavenIntegration) for offline mode. You can use the [settings](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-settings/settings.html) to find out where this is and delete it.